# Unpartition Hard Drive Debian

Tags: debian, partition

just wondering how I can unpartition a hard drive under debian.

i recently partitioned it using

```
cfdisk /dev/sdb
```

and would like to revert what I did.

Thanks

Comment: If revert means 'undo all my changes, and automatically put things back the way they were before', that's not going to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
cfdisk /dev/sdb
```

then use command "d" for the each partition.

```
    man cfdisk
    COMMANDS
    d      Delete the current partition.  This will convert the current partition into    free space and merge it with any free space immediately surrounding the current partition. A     partition already marked as free space or marked as unusable cannot be deleted.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1
```